# Как найти сумму объектов в массиве на javascript

Tags: javascript

Мне задали тестовое задание где нужно сделать интерактивную таблицу на js   с подстановкой данных из массива.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnA47.png

В общем я встал на том моменте посчитать сумму значений ключа real_time у определенного и добавить это все в столб отработанное время. Нашел сумму с помощью reduce, но не могу понять как мне подставить это значение в таблицу.
Уж очень хочется сделать это задание.Дайте хотя бы подсказку как решить

```js
const table = document.querySelector('.table');
const tbody = document.querySelector('.tbody');
const users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Павел',
    login: 'Pavel',
    role: 'менеджер',
    action: '',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Егор',
    login: 'Pavel',
    role: 'менеджер',
    action: '',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Дмитрий',
    login: 'Pavel',
    role: 'менеджер',
    action: '',
  },
];

const data = [{
    id: 1,
    id_user: 1,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 3,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    id_user: 2,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 3,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    id_user: 3,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 3,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },

];
//здесь нахожу сумму отработанного времени у определенного пользователя
const summed = data.reduce((acc, record) => {
  const {
    id_user,
    real_time
  } = record;

  if (!acc[id_user]) acc[id_user] = {
    real_time: 0
  };

  acc[id_user].real_time += real_time;

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(summed);

//Здесь добавляю name из массива users
const usermap = {};
users.forEach(function(user) {
  usermap[user.id] = user;
});
data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.user = usermap[item.id_user];

});

//создаю таблицу со значениями
const renderTable = () => {

  for (let user of data) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');

    let td1 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.innerHTML = user.id_user;
    tr.appendChild(td1);

    let td2 = document.createElement('td');
    td2.innerHTML = user.user.name;
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    let td3 = document.createElement('td');
    td3.innerHTML = user.real_time;
    tr.appendChild(td3);

    let td4 = document.createElement('td');
    td4.innerHTML = user.execution_time;
    tr.appendChild(td4);


    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }


}
renderTable();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <!-- Обязательные метатеги -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./blocks/index.css">
  <title>Привет мир!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">Пользователь</th>
        <th scope="col">Отработанное время</th>
        <th scope="col">Переработка</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">

    </tbody>
  </table>


  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: а куда ты хочешь добавить это число?

Answer (score 1):

Решение из вопроса по-моему содержит смысловую ошибку, которую исправил в примере ниже. Ошибка заключается в том, что перебирается не тот массив.
Вывод таблицы пользователей предполагает цикл по массиву *пользователей* (`users`) - но код из вопроса почему-то перебирает массив данных (`data`).

**Почему перебирать следует именно массив пользователей, а не массив данных?**
Давай на минутку забудем о том что просто естественно/логично, и внимательнее посмотрим на суть поставленной задачи: "суммировать время каждого пользователя из данных".
Задача практически говорит нам, что данные могут содержать ***несколько** записей об одном пользователе*. Иначе, если в данных всегда будет лишь одна запись на каждого пользователя - то и суммировать будет нечего, правильно? (задача в этом случае потеряет всякий смысл)
А теперь подумаем чуть дальше: что же случится когда будет несколько записей об одном юзере? Выводя табличку из массива данных, мы получим дублирование пользователей в таблице. Выводить одни и те же имена несколько раз, с разными показателями времени - это очень странно!.. и явно не то что нужно.

---

Соответственно, пересмотрим код:

- исправляем итерируемый массив в for-цикле построения таблички
- учитывая то что теперь перебор массива пользователей, нам становится совсем не нужно перед этим перебором линковать объект каждого пользователя в каждый объект массива данных (удаляем эту часть кода);
- если мы выводим результат по пользователям, и считаем сумму `real_time`, то и второе время `execution_time` наверное тоже надо суммировать (добавляем подсчет в функцию-редьюсер)
- хорошо бы видеть, работает ли вообще наше суммирование, а значит нам надо добавить еще как минимум одно слагаемое (в массив данных добавляем еще объектов с показателями времени - в примере я добавил только один объект данных, для пользователя с `id: 2`)

Результат:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('.table'),
      tbody = table.tBodies[0];
const users = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Павел', login: 'Pavel', role: 'менеджер', action: '' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Егор', login: 'Pavel', role: 'менеджер', action: '' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Дмитрий', login: 'Pavel', role: 'менеджер', action: '' },
];

const data = [
  { id: 1,
    id_user: 1,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 3,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    id_user: 2,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 3,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    id_user: 3,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 3,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    id_user: 2,
    task: "корректировка",
    execution_time: 2,
    real_time: 5,
    date: '21 jun 2021 year'
  },
];

//здесь нахожу сумму отработанного времени у определенного пользователя
const summed = data.reduce((acc, { id_user, real_time, execution_time }) => {
  let user = acc[id_user];
  if (!user)
    user = acc[id_user] = { real_time: 0, execution_time: 0 };
  user.real_time += real_time;
  user.execution_time += execution_time;
  return acc;
}, {});

// console.log(summed);

//Здесь добавляю name из массива users
const usermap = {};
users.forEach(function(user) {
  usermap[user.id] = user;
});

//создаю таблицу со значениями
const renderTable = () => {
  for (const user of users) {
    const tr = tbody.insertRow();
    tr.insertCell().textContent = user.id;
    tr.insertCell().textContent = user.name;
    tr.insertCell().textContent = summed[user.id].real_time;
    tr.insertCell().textContent = summed[user.id].execution_time;
  }
}
renderTable();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <!-- Обязательные метатеги -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./blocks/index.css">
  <title>Привет мир!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">Пользователь</th>
        <th scope="col">Отработанное время</th>
        <th scope="col">Переработка</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">

    </tbody>
  </table>


  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```